# How to use MsiSetExternalUI of Windows Installer in C# to handle the Cancel Button Click

Tags: c#, windows, installation, windows-installer

In Windows msi installation, I need to hook to the Cancel button click message. In the Custom Action, where MsiSetExternalUI is to be invoked and what should be the messageFilter?

If there is a better way of handling the Cancel button click event, it's highly appreciated. \

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

As per this documentation at MSDN ( http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa371248%28v=vs.85%29.aspx ) you can check the return value `IDCANCEL` for determining the Cancel Button Press.

Comment: Thanks for the response, Shekhar. I prefer a code sample on how to handle this in a installer file. At present, I call MsiSetExternalUI on the Install method, but the callback(MyInstallUIHandler) doesn't seem to be invoked. Also, what messageFilter should be used?